# Chevrloet Sail LS Engine starts missing when car is driving with AC on and it is hot outside

Tags: engine, ac, car

I have 2 problems .

1. If i am driving car for long and AC is on,When it is too hot or hot outside like May,June months in india.The car starts missing. after if suddenly a plac came where rain happens then it is working fine with AC.

2. When car is driving with AC on ,after few minutes a bad smell comes in car again and again.it is continous process if you drove car for say 5-8 hrs then it is happening every 15-20 minutes.

Comment: Get the compressor and its clutch diagnosed. As for the smell it's either the filter or the ac is set to bring fresh air in. This is just a guess, from what you wrote. My advise since GM closed it's service centers in your area just visit an AC technician for a diagnosis of the full system.